# Encryption with CryptoJS and decryption at java side?

Tags: java, security, encryption, cryptography, cryptojs

I want to encrypt some data on client side and Decrypt it on the server side but it is giving error on the server side saying that "Incorrect key".

Followings are my code snippets

```
var key = "randomKey";

        var hash  = CryptoJS.MD5(key);

        var hashedKey = btoa(hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64));

        var iv  = "1234567812345678";
        var message   = "#This is the plain text to encrypt#";


        var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(message, hashedKey, {iv : iv, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7} );


        var encrypteData=encrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.utf8);
```

That's how I am encrypting at client side. and sending "iv", "hashedKey" and "encryptedData" to server side.

we are decrypting this encrypted data at server side using java.
we are using AES/CBC/PKCS5Pading.
By passing iv, key and encrypted message to the "doFinal" method but we are getting error message as "Given final block not padded properly"

Edit -

```
Cipher decrypt = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
                decrypt.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, hashedKey,iv);
        byte[] decryptedMsg = decrypt.doFinal(encryptedMsg);
```

Comment: You should post decryption code at server side too.

Comment: @ANyarThar edit is done .

Comment: How use with `PKCS7Padding` in java as in CryptoJs? Another doubt is in client js `hashedKey` is encoded in `Base64`, u may need to decode back before final decryption.

Comment: @ANyarThar Thanks, But i didn't find pkcs7 padding in java fyi, I tried encryption at server side with pkcs5 padding and decryption at client side with pkcs7 padding and it was working fine.

the same key which is being used in encryption is being used for decryption too.

Comment: this link may help you pkcs7padding in java http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/security/encrypt-decrypt-with-with-aes-ecb-pkcs7padding/

Comment: What are you gaining from this that you don't already get from the underlying HTTPS connection?

Comment: @ANyarThar PKCS #5 and PKCS #7 paddings are the same for all practical purposes. See e.g. http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9043/what-is-the-difference-between-pkcs5-padding-and-pkcs7-padding

Comment: How did you actually create `encryptedMsg`, `hashedKey` and `iv` in the Java code? I'm pretty sure that the AES encryption itself is OK, but that leaves the input parameters.

Comment: @owlstead i am passing the same hashedKey, iv and encryptedMessage to the server side from client side.

Comment: **How** did you actually pass `encryptedMsg`, `hashedKey` and `iv` from the client to the server?

Comment: @owlstead I am directly passing them means copying from client side  and pasting it on the server side as text. my plan was if it is succeeded then will create one service to exchange it.

Answer (score 0):

Ciphertext contains of random bytes, not all of which can be represented as (UTF-8) characters. So:

```
var encrypteData=encrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.utf8);
```

may introduce or leave out characters, meaning that the ciphertext is not received correctly at the Java side. Please make sure that you base 64 encode all bytes that need to be represented by text, and if text needs to be converted to bytes, always specify a character encoding.

Comment: I tried converting encryptedData to Base64 then passing it to server but get no luck.

Comment: please tell me one thing that can there be any possibility of anything that CryptoJS library is adding by itself internally that i am missing at server side?

Comment: Try validating all input / output right before calling the encryption method in hexadecimals; if the input is wrong for a single bit, you will end up with garbage.